# Arguments of hook_file_download_access_alter()

Tags: hooks

```
function hook_file_download_access_alter(&$grants, $field, $entity_type, $entity) {
  // For our example module, we always enforce the rules set by node module.
  if (isset($grants['node'])) {
    $grants = array('node' => $grants['node']);
  }
}
```

The arguments `$field`, `$entity_type`, `$entity` are not used in the  implementation. What are these arguments used for, when the function is called?

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to use `$field`, `$entity_type` and `$entity` in your implementation of [hook_file_download_access_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!file!file.api.php/function/hook_file_download_access_alter/7), if you do not want to.

You should use theses arguments if you need to handle files differently depending on which field of which entity they belong to.

For example, [node_file_download_access()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_file_download_access/7) restricts access on files to people that can view the node. If you want to remove this restriction for nodes of a specific type `foo`, you would have to check whether `$entity_type == 'node'`and whether `$entity->type == 'foo'` and grant access if this is the case.

Comment: While the answer is correct, note that the last argument is currently not actually passed to the hook, this is a that has been fixed in 8.x and is currently being backported to 7.x.

Comment: thanks its help me .when function dont return anything what actual happen. ??

Comment: The return value is ignored, so it does not matter what you return (if anything). Altering the file download access is achieved by modifying the `$grants` argument. The documentation is misleading in this respect, an [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1753976) has been filed.